# Nothing happens when I login to Facebook, after moving to swift 3 xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Facebook & Firebase to connect users with my app.
Everything worked great before I moved to swift 3 and Xcode 8.

**Before the move:**
A view should be appear after the user has logged in to his facebook user.
The log in button should disappear.

**After the move:**
Nothing happens. The view doesn't show up and the log in button changes to <kbd>Log out</kbd> and doesn't disappear.

This is my `didComepleteWith` code:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        print("user logged in")
        self.loginButton.isHidden = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        if error != nil {
            self.loginButton.isHidden = false
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            print("???")
            //handle errors
        } else if result.isCancelled {
            self.loginButton.isHidden = false
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
            loginManager.logOut()
            //handle cancel
            print("canceled")
        } else {
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                print("user logged to firebase app")

            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i m assuming since the button title changes , u actually get the callBack with success in the fb manager/wrapper ;
could u post the block where u handle success just to give us a better understanding of what the problem might be

Comment: Sure, Added as you asked. But I don't get any print message when it's success to log in (it needs to print 'DONE')

Comment: check again and see if the button is actually connected to that method , migration could ve affected that , especially if you are using a storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I am having a few problems with the Facebook login with Firebase. It has to do with the way Keychain Access works in iOS 10 / Swift 3. I was able to get it to work with the simulator by:

Going into the Xcode project's target and clicking on "Compatibilities." You can then turn on "Keychain Sharing."

As far as getting it to work on a real device, I haven't gotten that to work but hopefully someone else has and can edit this answer!

Comment: Yeah, Keychain Sharing allows a lot of functionality, but for your purpose, I believe all you need to do is turn Keychain Sharing on